# Calculating SUM() results from subqueries into a total

Tags: mysql, sql

My brain is starting to hurt with this query and I would appreciate some guidance. What I am trying to get as the result of this query are three values: **attendanceScore**, **lootScore**, and **totalScore** (attendanceScore - lootScore).

- Attendance is tracked across three tables: `attendance`, `attendancelog`, and `attendancevalues`.

  - `attendance` records an individual's attendance status attached to an `attendancelog` record. There are types of attendance such as "attended", "missed", and "called out".
  - `attendancelog` is the parent record which records the event type, title and date as well as  who logged the attendance and when.
  - `attendancevalues` is a config table that matches the attendance `type` from `attendance` and the event `type` from `attendancelog` and returns a configurable `value` FLOAT.
- Loot is tracked across two tables: `loot` and `loottypes`.

  - `loot` logs each individual item, who received it and when and what `type` of loot it was (Primary, Secondary, Free-for-all).
  - `loottypes` is a config table that takes the `type` from `loot` and returns a configurable `cost` FLOAT.

---

After some work I have come up with a working query to get `attendanceScore` and `lootScore`:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(t3.`value`)
FROM `attendance` t1
    INNER JOIN `attendancelog` t2
        ON t2.`id` = t1.`attendancelog_id`
    INNER JOIN `attendancevalues` t3
        ON t3.`eventtype_id` = t2.`type` AND t3.`attendancetype_id` = t1.`type`
WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3) as attendanceScore,

(SELECT SUM(t2.`cost`) 
    FROM `loot` t1
        INNER JOIN `loottypes` t2
            ON t2.`id` = t1.`type`
    WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3) as lootScore
```

I know this doesn't work, but I tried to add `(attendanceScore - lootScore)` to the query but it says those fields are not available. That is ultimately what I need to complete the query.

I *can* get the result I want by copying each of the subqueries directly into `(attendanceScore - lootScore)` but it is just absolutely hideous and I'm sure unnecessary:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(t3.`value`)
FROM `attendance` t1
    INNER JOIN `attendancelog` t2
        ON t2.`id` = t1.`attendancelog_id`
    INNER JOIN `attendancevalues` t3
        ON t3.`eventtype_id` = t2.`type` AND t3.`attendancetype_id` = t1.`type`
WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3) as attendanceScore,

(SELECT SUM(t2.`cost`) 
    FROM `loot` t1
        INNER JOIN `loottypes` t2
            ON t2.`id` = t1.`type`
    WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3) as lootScore,

(
    (SELECT SUM(t3.`value`)
    FROM `attendance` t1
        INNER JOIN `attendancelog` t2
            ON t2.`id` = t1.`attendancelog_id`
        INNER JOIN `attendancevalues` t3
            ON t3.`eventtype_id` = t2.`type` AND t3.`attendancetype_id` = t1.`type`
    WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3) - (SELECT SUM(t2.`cost`) 
    FROM `loot` t1
        INNER JOIN `loottypes` t2
            ON t2.`id` = t1.`type`
    WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3)
) as totalScore
```

Could someone help me understand what methods to use for cleaning this up into something more streamlined and efficient?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Just use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: @RadimBača MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an inline view

```
SELECT attendanceScore,
        lootScore,
        attendanceScore - lootScore as totalScore
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT SUM(t3.`value`)
        FROM `attendance` t1
        INNER JOIN `attendancelog` t2
            ON t2.`id` = t1.`attendancelog_id`
        INNER JOIN `attendancevalues` t3
            ON t3.`eventtype_id` = t2.`type` AND t3.`attendancetype_id` = t1.`type`
        WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3
    ) as attendanceScore,
    (
        SELECT SUM(t2.`cost`) 
        FROM `loot` t1
        INNER JOIN `loottypes` t2 ON t2.`id` = t1.`type`
        WHERE t1.`user_id` = 3) as lootScore
) t
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to get this format to work based on another similar question but wasn't quite there. This worked perfectly as-is in MySQL.